# How to create Python exception without stack trace?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I would like to create a Python exception that does not print the stack trace (for simple user errors). I have created a function below that wraps a custom class, but I would prefer to bake it into the custom exception class directly,  would that be possible somehow?

```
class UserError(Exception):
    pass

def throw_user_error(s_msg):
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
    raise UserError(s_msg)
    sys.tracebacklimit = 1000
```

Comment: That sounds like a job that should be handled by your own error handling and reporting code, not by the exception class.

Comment: try adding a print and then sys.exit()

Comment: @Yash But I don't want to exit. If the user for example is working in the repl a simple error should be shown without a long trace, after which the user should be able to continue to work (using the hint from the exception)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you should create custom handler, not the exception. And this handler even already exists in the standard library:
For example:

```py
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass

from contextlib import suppress

def main():
    with suppress(CustomException):
        # throw this error without consequences
        raise CustomException() 
        print('This won\'t be reached')   
    print('Exiting normally anyway')

main()
```

---

```py
Exiting normally anyway
```

And one more effective way to hide traceback is to replace it:

```py
In [30]: def fn(n=0):
    ...:     if n <= 0:
    ...:         raise Exception
    ...:     return fn(n-1)
    ...:
    ...: try:
    ...:     fn(10)
    ...: except Exception as e:
    ...:     raise e.with_traceback(None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-bc3c4e86e3cc> in <module>
      7     fn(10)
      8 except Exception as e:
----> 9     raise e.with_traceback(None)

Exception:
```

Without this line (believe me or not) if we propagate the exception further, we'll see the long-long stack of recursive calls.